# Array exists but items aren't being pushed into it

Tags: ruby

So, here's my issue. When I create a new List class at the beginning of the program runner, it's supposed to create a new array (`all_tasks`). Each time I add a new task, the task should be pushed to the array. Then, when I show the array, it should list each task.

The issue is when I use the `write_to_file` method. I get an error `Undefined local variable or method 'all_tasks'`. I made another method case in where I can look at the array, and it doesn't look like the new tasks are being pushed into the array. Yet, when I use the `show_tasks` method, it's able to list everything in the array.

If someone could not just grab me a solution but also elaborate a lot, I'd appreciate that. I'm still a beginner with Ruby.

As a side note, the `show_tasks` method also lists each item in the array twice, once using `puts` but then again right below it.

```
 ## Classes ##

    #List Class - Used for anything involving the list
    class List
      attr_accessor :all_tasks
      def initialize
        @all_tasks = Array.new
      end
      def add(task)
        all_tasks << task
      end
      def show_tasks
        all_tasks.each do |x|
          puts "- #{x}"
        end
      end
    end

    #Task Class - Used for anything involving Tasks
    class Task
      attr_reader :description
      alias to_s description
      def initialize(description)
        @description = description
      end
    end

    ## Modules ##
    module Promptable
      def prompt(message = "What would you like to do?", symbol = ">: ")
        print "#{message}\n"
        print symbol
        gets.chomp
      end
      def show_menu
        menu
      end
    end


    module Menu
      def menu
        puts "\nHere's a list of options that you can choose from: \n
        'add' - Add a task to the list \n
        'write' - Write the list to a file \n
        'show' - Shows current tasks in list \n
        'q' - Quits from current session \n
        \n Please Select an option"
      end
    end

    #Methods - various methods
    def desc_to_s
      description
    end
    def write_to_file(filename)
      if all_tasks == nil
        puts "Error - Array is nil"
      else
        IO.write(filename, @all_tasks.map(&:desc_to_s).join("\n"))
      end
    end

    #Program Runner
    if __FILE__ == $PROGRAM_NAME
      include Menu
      include Promptable
      my_list = List.new
      puts "\nWelcome to do ToDoLoo! Create your ToDo List \n"
      until ['q'].include?(user_input = prompt(show_menu).downcase)
        case user_input
          # Developer only controls
        when 'devshowtask'
          my_list.each do |x|
            puts "#{x}"
          end
        when 'add'
          my_list.add(Task.new(prompt("What task would you like to create?")))
        when 'show'
          puts "Here's a current list of all your tasks:\n"
          puts my_list.show_tasks
          prompt("Press enter to continue")
        when 'menu'
          prompt(show_menu)
        when 'write'
          write_to_file(prompt("What would you like to name the file"))
        else puts "\nThat is not a valid command"
        end
      end
    end
```

Comment: you initialize `all_tasks` when you make a new list, but when you call `all_tasks` in the `write_to_file` method...well take a look.  there needs to be some connection between those two objects and there isn't.  I understand what you are trying to do here, but maybe you're trying to run before you walk.

Comment: Why is there not an "@" sign in front of the all_tasks arrays in the methods?

Answer (score 1):

`write_to_file` is a method of the module Menu but Menu isn't mixed-in in List, it doesn't know about `all_tasks`. Also, this line

```
if all_tasks == nil
```

in Ruby is written like

```
if all_tasks.nil?
```

or

```
unless all_tasks
```

Comment: The write_to_file method isn't in the module Menu. How is it part of it?

Answer (score 0):

`attr_accessor` just makes two methods, a getter and a setter. When you do `all_tasks << task`, the getter is called, and returns the current value of @all_tasks, an anonymous array. Then `task` is added to that array. (The array is implicitly returned from `add` but I think that won't help.) Notice that @all_tasks was not modified.

You could do this:

```
all_tasks = all_tasks << task
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem, thanks to @dax, was that `write_to_file` method was called without calling the array to call it to.

Instead of `write_to_file` in the `'write'` case it should've been `my_list.write_to_file`